# Convert sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have used this query in sql,pls convert this query to use for access database.

Table structure is UserID,Username,LogDate,LogTime

```
WITH  
    [TableWithRowId] as 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserId,LogDate,LogTime) RowId, * FROM @YourTable), 
    [OddRows] as  
    (SELECT * FROM [TableWithRowId] WHERE rowid % 2 = 1), 
    [EvenRows] as 
    (SELECT *, RowId-1 As OddRowId FROM [TableWithRowId] WHERE rowid % 2 = 0) 
SELECT  
    [OddRows].UserId, 
    [OddRows].UserName, 
    [OddRows].LogDate, 
    [OddRows].LogTime, 
    [EvenRows].LogDate, 
    [EvenRows].LogTime  
FROM 
    [OddRows] LEFT JOIN [EvenRows] 
    ON [OddRows].RowId = [EvenRows].OddRowId
```

Comment: @nisha is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708525/ms-access-query-for-time ?

Comment: yes sir it is related with it

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Access doesn't support `WITH`. You'll have to use a temp table for `TableWithRowId` (assuming some equivalent of `ROW_NUMBER()` exists, which may not). The other tables, you can just convert to sub-selects.